# Android import Mupdf as a module error

Tags: android, mupdf

I want to import mupdf into my application in Android Studio.But when did it,I got an error.Below is error:

```
Error:(63, 0) Cannot get property 'absolutePath' on null object
<a href="openFile:F:\Android_Studio_Project\HelloToone\android\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

The relevant code is in build.gradle.Below is the code:

```
def ndkBuildPath = plugins.getPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder().absolutePath + File.separator + 'ndk-build'
if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
    ndkBuildPath +='.cmd'
}
```

How to slove it? Thank you.

Comment: I edited it.Thank you.

Comment: Check what getNdkFolder() is returning.

Comment: I can't check it.Because Android Studio prompt me that it cannot resolve symbol 'sdkHandler'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this error.I didn't install Android NDK in Android Studio before.When I install the NDK,the Gradle restarted build my application.The error resolved.